# Create a dictionary from an extrange list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have this input in `Python` (3.7):

```
params_list = ['SN:783HJ_DN', ' release tag:v2.2.4', ' build Feb  5 2019 16:13:34\n']
```

And I need a dictionary in which if I query

```
params_list['SN'], I got '783HJ_DN'
```

Same with the others (but in build parameter there's no ':'). Even though I tried this and I think I am to the solution:

```
list_dict = dict(item.split(":") for item in params_list.split(","))
```

Instead, I got this output error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/alvaro/parse.py", line 9, in  param_dict = dict(item.split(":") for item in params.split(",")) ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required

Comment: This would be simple if all the keys were followed by a colon. But since "build" is followed by a space, it may be impossible to write a completely unambiguous solution. There's no single rule that describes how all the keys should be extracted. "All characters before the first colon" means " build Feb  5 2019 16" becomes a key; "All characters before the first instance of a space or colon" means " release" becomes a key instead of "release tag".

Comment: Note that you cannot name something list, as it is reserved.

Comment: *shouldn't, you can name a variable whatever you like, but you override the original functionality.

Comment: @zabop, true, just changed the real name to make it easier to understand

EDIT: updated list name

Comment: @kevin, I understand, then I am going to leave that "parameter". I am not parsing the last one about the build

Comment: I would also note: why are you calling params_list.split(",")? params_list is not a string separated by commas, right? Each key-value pair is already separated from each other, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you expect only one ':' in the string items of the list :

```
list1 = {i.split(":")[0] : i.split(":")[1] for i in params_list if i.count(":") ==1}
```